# Squish/aggregate rows based on index conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new with Pandas and have been struggling with a particular problem for several days now. I have a dataset of crypto pricing in 1 minute intervals all the way back to 2012 ([link](https://www.kaggle.com/tencars/392-crypto-currency-pairs-at-minute-resolution)).

It looks like this:

```
                open         close      high       low     volume
timestamp                                                        
1364774820     93.25     93.300000     93.30     93.25  93.300000
1364774880    100.00    100.000000    100.00    100.00  93.300000
1364774940     93.30     93.300000     93.30     93.30  33.676862
1364775060     93.35     93.470000     93.47     93.35  20.000000
1364775120     93.47     93.470000     93.47     93.47   2.021627
...              ...           ...       ...       ...        ...
1615302420  54566.00  54584.000000  54585.00  54566.00   0.442658
1615302480  54586.00  54586.733478  54598.00  54586.00   2.802892
1615302540  54586.00  54513.000000  54587.00  54501.00   9.255249
1615302600  54511.00  54464.316913  54511.00  54456.00  12.339995
1615302660  54456.00  54456.000000  54460.00  54456.00   1.023890

[3244157 rows x 5 columns]
```

What I'm trying to do is derive a 5-minute interval set from this data. Which means I need to do the following:

- Set the index of a new dataframe in 300s intervals starting with 1364774700

  ```
  ts = data.index[0]
  ts -= (ts % 300)
  te = data.index[-1]
  te -= (te % 300)
  t5min = [x for x in range(ts, te + 300, 300)]
  df = pd.DataFrame(index=t5min, columns=data.columns)
  ```
- Sum all volume data in 1min intervals that fall within the 300s intervals in the new df
- Adjust ohlc for the new 5min interval, based on the 1min interval datapoints that fall within range
- Use the resulting dataframe as an input to more new dataframes at increasing time intervals (15min, 20min, 1hr, etc..)

I've come up with a few janky solutions, but they are *super* slow and would probably take days to execute. I've also looked into the use of groupby/agg/apply to no avail just quite yet. Since I'm new to Pandas, I was hoping to learn from some experts and hopefully do this a little more elegantly.

EDIT: Not necessarily looking for a complete solution, but if anyone can point me in the direction of some examples or functions I can use to do this, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Approach

Convert the `index` of the dataframe to `datetime` index using `pd.to_datetime` then `floor` this index to `5min` frequency to create a `5min` grouper, then `group` the dataframe on this grouper and aggregate the columns `open` using `first`, `close` using `last`, `high` using `max`, `low` using `min` and `volume` using `sum`:

```
agg_dict = {'open':'first', 'close': 'last', 
            'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'volume': 'sum'}

out = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s').floor('5min')).agg(agg_dict)
```

#### Result

For the sample dataframe

```
>>> out
                         open     close      high       low      volume
timestamp                                                              
2013-04-01 00:05:00     93.25     93.30    100.00     93.25  220.276862
2013-04-01 00:10:00     93.35     93.47     93.47     93.35   22.021627
2021-03-09 15:05:00  54566.00  54513.00  54598.00  54501.00   12.500799
2021-03-09 15:10:00  54511.00  54456.00  54511.00  54456.00   13.363885
```

Comment: Wow! You sir, are some sort of wizard. This did exactly what I needed, and essentially in two lines of code. Unbelievable. Thanks!!